# Is there a way to only move the area in the circle to a different area?

Tags: texturing

Is there a way to only move the area in the circle to a different area?

I have to use version 2.79b

[image]

I'm new and I need to move the two sleeves of the shirt to a different area but I don't even know what it's called to even try to look it up.

Comment: To select specific things in the UV editor, select any face on its surface (UV map side). Then, with your mouse still over the same section, press L to select the whole "island" (floating UV piece).

Comment: I know how to select specific sections. I stated I wanted to MOVE that specific section without the other unselected area being affected.

Comment: After making your selection, Press G and move it, or if you want it constrained to an axis, either G->X or G->Y?